# Mongoid unique children

Tags: ruby, mongoid

I'm creating a multi-tenant application and am trying to figure out how to model this relationship with Mongoid. I have a `Site` model which `has_many :domains`, or `embeds_many`, or even uses an array of strings if that will work. I want to validate that only unique domains can be associated (so two `Sites` can't have the same domain). I also want to be able to find a site by a given domain.

How would I represent this using Mongoid? Also, how would I query for the `Site` by a given domain?

Answer (score 1):

You better go with the has_many association.

In the domain model just do and you will be good. Assuming you want unique domain names, if url just change it.

```
validates_uniqueness_of :name
```

If you embed it, you can't do that validation easily, you you need to fetch all site and domains, or keep a different collection with just the domain names to see if it exists. Same for query the site with a given domain. Because you couldn't get the domain, without knowing the site it belongs.

---

If you do the proper relations as

```
class Site
  field :name
  has_many :domains
end

class Domain
  field :name
  belongs_to :site
end
```

You can then do, like in ActiveRecord

```
some_domain.site
```

docs: http://mongoid.org/en/mongoid/docs/relations.html#has_many

Comment: Okay, sounds good. Could you provide an example of how I would look up the site based on a given domain?